# How to detect duplicates in this scenario accounting for internal differentiation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, sql-server-2016

I have this SQL Query and it is fucntional that it detects duplicate occurences of [Type].

```
select Type, count(1) as 'Occurences' from [dbo].[Policy]
 where PolicyDescription ='ABC' 
group by Type
 HAVING COUNT(1)>1
```

BUT the same table [Policy] also has a column [Id] and my query above does not differentiate based on [Id].

I would like the above query to account for only the results where the [Id] is different too.

What change should I implement ?

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @Policy AS TABLE
(
    ID int,
    PolicyDescription char(3),
    Type int
)

INSERT INTO @Policy(ID, PolicyDescription, Type) VALUES
(1, 'ABC', 123),
(1, 'ABC', 123),
(2, 'ABC', 456),
(3, 'ABC', 567),
(4, 'ABC', 567),
(3, 'ABC', 567)
```

**Current Result**

```
 Type | Occurences
------|------------
   123|           2
   567|           3
```

**Desired Result**

```
 Type | Occurences
------|------------
   567|           2
```

Comment: Please read the first two paragraphs of the [TSQL tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Add `ID` to the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Larnu Grouping by `ID` would provide `Type` and `ID` combinations that appear multiple times, OP is looking for Types that contain multiple IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine your `COUNT` with `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(DISTINCT Id) AS 'Occurences'
FROM Policy
WHERE PolicyDescription = 'ABC'
GROUP BY Type
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change:

```
from policy
```

to:

```
from (select distinct * from policy)
```

like this:

```
select t.type, count(1) as 'Occurences' 
from (select distinct * from policy) t
where t.policydescription ='ABC' 
group by t.type
having count(1) > 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=6852099c34ab3d44a44bbb7c04ced9bb)